# Blend, big xaml files (cad)

Tags: xaml, expression-blend, cad

I'm trying to import cad model into blend and then make some storyboard on it.
Idea was to export xaml file from solidworks and then import it to blend.

File open in blend, model is displayed correctly and every thing works until i zoom/move or make any action that results in immediate program crash.

Xaml file is about 5mb, and outside blend works fine in my program i can rotate,zoom it freely with good performance.

Have anyone encountered similar problem, or have good method for converting cad->xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I did when working on an augmented reality feature in a desktop aplication.

My solution was to convert the object to fbx format and use the XMA game studio controls to view it. Then I was able to do what I wish in blend.